# How to close embedded modalDialog

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

I have modalDialog embedded  into other `modalDialog`. When I run `modalButton` both of them closed. 
How to close only embedded `modalDialog`?

Now :  [image]
Code :

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("one","Press")  
  ),
  server <- function(input, output,session) {
    observeEvent(input$one,{
      showModal(modalDialog(            
        actionButton("two","Press 2"),
        footer = tagList(
          modalButton("Cancel")
        )))
    })
    observeEvent(input$two,{
      showModal(modalDialog(
        "OKAY",
        footer = tagList(
          modalButton("Cancel")
        )))
    })
})
```

Need : 
[image]

Comment: The problem is that a new modal dialog seems to replace the previous one. So there is no "closing the second one" thing. I guess a workaround would be once the second is closed, you recreate again the first immediatly after, so the user almost doesn't see the trick

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure what you want to display in modal but maybe you can have a look at the `sweetalertR` package :

```
 library(shiny)
library(sweetalertR)
shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sweetalert('#one',
      title = "Are you sure?",
      text = "Press here for some magic",
      type = "warning",
      showCancelButton = TRUE,
      confirmButtonColor = '#DD6B55',
      confirmButtonText = 'Yes, Confirm!',
      closeOnConfirm = FALSE,
      evalFunction = 'function(){swal("OKAY!", "Thank you PorkChop!", "success")}'
    ),
    actionButton("one","Press")  
  ),
  server <- function(input, output,session) { })
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! I have never used the `sweetalertR` package before, it looks really good.