# How to close a modal but with the original model remain open

Tags: shiny, modal-dialog

I am facing a problem: I created a modal inside a modal using shiny, but when I close the inside modal, it automatically closes the entire modal (outside one), is there a way that I can just close the current pop-out modal and remain the outside one open ?

Comment: Can you share a minimum working example? You can use `shinyjs::hide` just to close that modal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close embedded modalDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464847/how-to-close-embedded-modaldialog)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to create a MWE Solution for your problem.

- This has two Modals
- Inner Modal is triggered when the `Ok` button of Outer Modal is clicked
- Outer Modal is shown back when the `Dismiss` button of Inner Modal is clicked

  ```
  shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
      actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")  ),

    server = function(input, output) {

      dataModal <- function() {
         modalDialog(
          span('First Modal'),

          footer = tagList(
            modalButton("Cancel"),
            actionButton("ok", "OK")
          )
         )

      }

      subModal <- function(){
        modalDialog(
        span('Inner Modal '),

        footer = tagList(
          modalButton("Cancel"),
          actionButton('dismiss','Dismiss Inner Modal')

        ))
      }

      observeEvent(input$show, {
        showModal(dataModal())
      })


      observeEvent(input$ok, {
         showModal(subModal())
      })

      observeEvent(input$dismiss, {
        showModal(dataModal())
      })



    }
  )
  ```

Comment: nice trick! though the user should bare in mind the consequences of the first modal being *actually* destroyed: it should be avoided if there are some userinputs stored in the first modal, or if the first modal takes some time to load, or if we want to launch some specific process when first "ok" button is pressed it will do it twice, etc.

Comment: That's right agenis. Have you found a viable solution for this issue? Not sure how to approach this, since the form data in the modal is volatile.